# XEP-198 stream Management not working in Openfire 4.0.1

Tags: openfire, smack, xmp

I am new in openfire, i have setup openfire 4.0.1. Everything is working fine. But Stream Management is not working while it has been resolved.
https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/OF-446 
But when user sending chat message no acknowledge getting back to sender.
I downloaded source code from here http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp

I have enable streammanagement in smack client while making connection.
xMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
xMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);

Please suggest me if anything need to do with in openfire to enable stream management or anything i am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Incoming/Outgoing traffic and check what packet is sent by Smack for enabling stream management and if it gets acknowledgement from server about stream management enabled.
Please provide the packets here too.